# Bash: increment a variable from a script every time when I run that script

Tags: bash, increment, auto-increment

I want that a variable from a script to be incremented every time when I run that script. Something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash    
n=0   #the variable that I want to be incremented
next_n=$[$n+1]
sed -i "2s/.*/n=$next_n/" ${0}
echo $n
```

will do the job, but is not so good if I will add other lines to the script before the line in which the variable is set  and I forget to update the line `sed -i "2s/.*/n=$next_n/" ${0}`.

Also I prefer to not use another file in which to keep the variable value.

Some other idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash    
n=0;#the variable that I want to be incremented
next_n=$[$n+1]
sed -i "/#the variable that I want to be incremented$/s/=.*#/=$next_n;#/" ${0}
echo $n
```

Comment: It may be something in the right way. But doesn't work for me. Can you review your answer?

Comment: hi i should add a \ before the $.try again please.and make sure the line you declared variable n ends with comment #the variable ... just as your sample code does.

Comment: It was better before. The problem is that the line that contain `sed` command is edited also.

Comment: Well done! I will use `sed -i "/#the variable that I want to be incremented$/s/n=.*#/n=$next_n;#/" ${0}` in case if I will add another line like: `m=0;#the variable that I want to be incremented`.

Comment: @eeeyes Can you please comment the complete script since as an when I run the script answered above the value doesn't change i.e. each time 0 is printed.

Answer (score 6):

A script is run in a subshell, which means its variables are forgotten once the script ends and are not propagated to the parent shell which called it. To run a command list in the current shell, you could either `source` the script, or write a function. In such a script, plain

```
(( n++ ))
```

would work - but only when called from the same shell. If the script should work from different shells, or even after switching the machine off and on again, saving the value in a file is the simplest and best option. It might be easier, though, to store the variable value in a different file, not the script itself:

```
[[ -f saved_value ]] || echo 0 > saved_value
n=$(< saved_value)
echo $(( n + 1 )) > saved_value
```

Changing the script when it runs might have strange consequences, especially when you change the size of the script (which might happen at 9 → 10).

Comment: what if we want to confined the n variable to increment till some particular value like till 7 only and then it goes back to zero again. ?

Comment: @GURUSINGH Start a new question to ask a new question.